# How to send message to the user by using telegram id and python_telegram_bot library?

Tags: telegram-bot, message, python-telegram-bot, sendmessage

I want to send the message to anybody by using his telegramid and python_telegram_bot library.
I can send the message to me by using below code but if I put other's id then I can not send the message and it says `chat not found` message.

```
updater = Updater(mybot_token, use_context=True)
updater.bot.send_message(chat_id = receiver_id, text="welcome")
```

I am not sure why it is only possible to send the message to me, not the others even though I puth the chat_id as their telegram_id.

Answer (score 0):

Bots can only send messages to users that have already started the bot. See the [Telegram Bot docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots#4-how-are-bots-different-from-humans).